# Brand new 802.11ax (WLAN6) laptop is slow on iperf3

Tags: networking, wireless, iperf

I own a brand new Lenovo [Thinkpad X1 Extreme Gen 2](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201906-27150) my WiFi AP is an [AVM Fritz! Box 4040](https://avm.de/produkte/fritzbox/fritzbox-4040/technische-daten/). The AP is capable of 802.11ac.

The **notebook is certified for Ubuntu 18.04** (see link above). **I run Ubuntu 19.10**, because of the newer kernel.

I also have a HomeServer (Debian) on which I run iperf3 server (without any special params). It's connected via Gigabit Ethernet to the AP. **If wired, the laptop reaches stable 944 Mbit/s.**

If it's using Wifi, the speed is set to 780 Mbit if enabled close to the AP. If I switch to WiFi farer away (1-2 walls in between) then it's set to 144 Mbit. The speed is not adjusted automatically if I get closer to the AP. (**Problem 1**).

**Problem 2** is this: I'm sitting 2m in front of the AP (2m) during this, Disabled and re-enabled wifi to get 780 Mbit/s. But what actually happens:

```
iperf3 -c 192.168.170.11
Connecting to host 192.168.170.11, port 5201
[  5] local 192.168.170.44 port 44416 connected to 192.168.170.11 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  54.8 MBytes   460 Mbits/sec    0   1.60 MBytes       
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec    9   1.41 KBytes       
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  5.00 MBytes  42.0 Mbits/sec  1203    252 KBytes       
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec  46.2 MBytes   388 Mbits/sec    0   1.42 MBytes       
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  123   17.0 KBytes       
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec  15.0 MBytes   126 Mbits/sec  909    167 KBytes       
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec   20   5.66 KBytes       
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec   12   2.83 KBytes       
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec   10   2.83 KBytes       
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  16.2 MBytes   136 Mbits/sec   94    779 KBytes       
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec   140 MBytes   117 Mbits/sec  2380             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec   137 MBytes   115 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

Where does those lags come from? It's reproduceable. I very fast burst, then extremely slow, then again a bit faster and then zero.

Already tried to turn off the power management but that does not seem to help and the change gets lost on re-connect.

```
sudo iwconfig wlp82s0 power off
```

Please ask for further info if needed.

Comment: What's your MTU? `ip link show` will show it. Try settiing the MTU to 1492 with `sudo ip set dev wlp82s0 mtu 1492`

Comment: It's 1500. I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: MTU was set to `Auto` in Ubuntus network configs. I changed it to `1492` but it did not change anything. BTW: Your `ip set` command does not work in Ubuntu.